# Radiobutton list and or dropdown together

Tags: usability

I have a system, where users can pick an item to confirm.

However, there's only space for few radio buttons, so I added a dropdown in order to pick more than just an option between 6 or 7 button buttons.

See this example below.

[image]

Are there any other possibilities I can make use of, as I need to have a few one-click (example radio button) options first.

The checkbox could be ignored, it will populate with other information with a postback.

Comment: What's the function of the checkbox at the far right? Note that if you want to create mockups, this site has an integrated tool you can use too. It works quite nicely.

Comment: What is the task? Is there default number? In e-commerce sites you could see appropriate controls for selecting number of items.

Comment: You may ignore the checkbox, thanks for your concern. It will populate the dropdown with other data instead of default.

The numbers are actually names of users, so not just numbers.
@AlexeyKolchenko Do you have an example or picture?

Comment: So do you want to show some frequent (popular) items and provide access to other items as well?

Comment: @AlexeyKolchenko Yes I do, most common, or a list with few (max 10) items as radiobuttons (this is jQuery on a radiobutton to make it look better) and dropdown with "other" not in the first 10. What's the best I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be as follows. See the items under the search bar.
[image]